# SQL Server 2008 query to run for last 8 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database for orders. Each order contains a date entered.

I have written a query that returns orders between x and y dates....and it works.

But now I need to write the query for each week for the past 8 weeks.

So first should query between Sunday and Saturday of this week. Should be able to determine what date Sunday of this week is.

Next query should query the previous week Sunday to Saturday.

Then the previous.

And so on........

Then I plan to join all together at end.

Any ideas?

I should have been more clear, here is the query I am using. I need to run this 8 times....
One for current week Sunday to sat..then previous and so on.

SELECT 
      [OrderDate],
     COUNT(*) AS OrderTotal
     FROM [Orders]
      WHERE Order_Date between '2013/06/05' AND'2013/06/11'
  group by OrderComp

Comment: Make a date table and join to it...

Comment: Dis question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Not the version I use personally but should be a fine generic date table creation script. Found it in like 2 seconds after googling create date table. Create one Join to it select by week.

```
--Make sure you set the Start and End Date below on row 58 and 59
--Create the tables
BEGIN TRY
 DROP TABLE [DimDate]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 --DO NOTHING
END CATCH
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate](
 --[DateSK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL--Use this line if you just want an autoincrementing counter AND COMMENT BELOW LINE
 [DateSK] [int] NOT NULL--TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT USE THIS LINE AND COMMENT ABOVE LINE.
 , [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
 , [Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 , [DaySuffix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL
 , [DayOfWeek] [varchar](9) NOT NULL
 , [DOWInMonth] [TINYINT] NOT NULL
 , [DayOfYear] [int] NOT NULL
 , [WeekOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 , [WeekOfMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 , [Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 , [MonthName] [varchar](9) NOT NULL
 , [Quarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 , [QuarterName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL
 , [Year] [char](4) NOT NULL
 , [StandardDate] [varchar](10) NULL
 , [HolidayText] [varchar](50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimDate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
 [DateSK] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


--Populate Date dimension

TRUNCATE TABLE DimDate

--IF YOU ARE USING THE YYYYMMDD format for the primary key then you need to comment out this line.
--DBCC CHECKIDENT (DimDate, RESEED, 60000) --In case you need to add earlier dates later.

DECLARE @tmpDOW TABLE (DOW INT, Cntr INT)--Table for counting DOW occurance in a month
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(1,0)--Used in the loop below
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(2,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(3,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(4,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(5,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(6,0)
INSERT INTO @tmpDOW(DOW, Cntr) VALUES(7,0)

DECLARE @StartDate datetime
 , @EndDate datetime
 , @Date datetime
 , @WDofMonth INT
 , @CurrentMonth INT

SELECT @StartDate = '1/1/2000'  -- Set The start and end date 
 , @EndDate = '1/1/2015'--Non inclusive. Stops on the day before this.
 , @CurrentMonth = 1 --Counter used in loop below.

SELECT @Date = @StartDate

WHILE @Date < @EndDate
 BEGIN

 IF DATEPART(MONTH,@Date) <> @CurrentMonth 
 BEGIN
 SELECT @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)
 UPDATE @tmpDOW SET Cntr = 0
 END

 UPDATE @tmpDOW
 SET Cntr = Cntr + 1
 WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW,@DATE)

 SELECT @WDofMonth = Cntr
 FROM @tmpDOW
 WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW,@DATE) 

 INSERT INTO DimDate
 (
 [DateSK],--TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT UNCOMMENT THIS LINE... Comment for autoincrementing.
 [Date]
 , [Day]
 , [DaySuffix]
 , [DayOfWeek]
 , [DOWInMonth]
 , [DayOfYear]
 , [WeekOfYear]
 , [WeekOfMonth] 
 , [Month]
 , [MonthName]
 , [Quarter]
 , [QuarterName]
 , [Year]
 , [StandardDate]
 )
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date,112), --TO MAKE THE DateSK THE YYYYMMDD FORMAT UNCOMMENT THIS LINE COMMENT FOR AUTOINCREMENT
 @Date [Date]
 , DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) [Day]
 , CASE 
 WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) IN (11,12,13) THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'th'
 WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 1 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'st'
 WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 2 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'nd'
 WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE),1) = 3 THEN CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'rd'
 ELSE CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) + 'th' 
 END AS [DaySuffix]
 , CASE DATEPART(DW, @DATE)
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
 WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
 WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
 WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
 WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
 WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
 END AS [DayOfWeek]
 , @WDofMonth [DOWInMonth]--Occurance of this day in this month. If Third Monday then 3 and DOW would be Monday.
 , DATEPART(dy,@Date) [DayOfYear]--Day of the year. 0 - 365/366
 , DATEPART(ww,@Date) [WeekOfYear]--0-52/53
 , DATEPART(ww,@Date) + 1 -
 DATEPART(ww,CAST(DATEPART(mm,@Date) AS VARCHAR) + '/1/' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,@Date) AS VARCHAR)) [WeekOfMonth]
 , DATEPART(MONTH,@DATE) [Month]--To be converted with leading zero later. 
 , DATENAME(MONTH,@DATE) [MonthName]
 , DATEPART(qq,@DATE) [Quarter]--Calendar quarter
 , CASE DATEPART(qq,@DATE) 
 WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
 WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
 WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
 END AS [QuarterName]
 ,DATEPART(YEAR,@Date) [Year]
 ,Right('0' + convert(varchar(2),MONTH(@Date)),2) + '/' + Right('0' + convert(varchar(2),DAY(@Date)),2) + '/' + convert(varchar(4),YEAR(@Date))

 SELECT @Date = DATEADD(dd,1,@Date)
 END


--Add HOLIDAYS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--THANKSGIVING --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Fourth THURSDAY in November.
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Thanksgiving Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 11 
 AND [DAYOFWEEK] = 'Thursday' 
 AND [DOWInMonth] = 4
GO

--CHRISTMAS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Christmas Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 12 AND [DAY] = 25

--4th of July ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Independance Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 7 AND [DAY] = 4

-- New Years Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'New Year''s Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 1 AND [DAY] = 1

--Memorial Day ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Last Monday in May
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Memorial Day'
FROM DimDate
WHERE DateSK IN 
 (
 SELECT MAX([DateSK])
 FROM dbo.DimDate
 WHERE [MonthName] = 'May'
 AND [DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
 GROUP BY [YEAR], [MONTH]
 )
--Labor Day -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--First Monday in September
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Labor Day'
FROM DimDate
WHERE DateSK IN 
 (
 SELECT MIN([DateSK])
 FROM dbo.DimDate
 WHERE [MonthName] = 'September'
 AND [DayOfWeek] = 'Monday'
 GROUP BY [YEAR], [MONTH]
 )

-- Valentine's Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Valentine''s Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 2 AND [DAY] = 14

-- Saint Patrick's Day -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Saint Patrick''s Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 3 AND [DAY] = 17
GO
--Martin Luthor King Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Third Monday in January starting in 1983
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Martin Luthor King Jr Day'
WHERE [MONTH] = 1--January
 AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
 AND [YEAR] >= 1983--When holiday was official
 AND [DOWInMonth] = 3--Third X day of current month.
GO
--President's Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Third Monday in February.
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'President''s Day'--select * from DimDate
WHERE [MONTH] = 2--February
 AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
 AND [DOWInMonth] = 3--Third occurance of a monday in this month.
GO
--Mother's Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Second Sunday of May
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Mother''s Day'--select * from DimDate
WHERE [MONTH] = 5--May
 AND [Dayofweek] = 'Sunday'
 AND [DOWInMonth] = 2--Second occurance of a monday in this month.
GO
--Father's Day ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Third Sunday of June
UPDATE DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Father''s Day'--select * from DimDate
WHERE [MONTH] = 6--June
 AND [Dayofweek] = 'Sunday'
 AND [DOWInMonth] = 3--Third occurance of a monday in this month.
GO
--Halloween 10/31 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET HolidayText = 'Halloween'
WHERE [MONTH] = 10 AND [DAY] = 31
--Election Day--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--The first Tuesday after the first Monday in November.
BEGIN TRY
 drop table #tmpHoliday
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
 --do nothing
END CATCH

CREATE TABLE #tmpHoliday(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), DateID int, Week TINYINT, YEAR CHAR(4), DAY CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #tmpHoliday(DateID, [YEAR],[DAY])
 SELECT [DateSK], [YEAR], [DAY]
 FROM dbo.DimDate
 WHERE [MONTH] = 11
 AND [Dayofweek] = 'Monday'
 ORDER BY YEAR, DAY

DECLARE @CNTR INT, @POS INT, @STARTYEAR INT, @ENDYEAR INT, @CURRENTYEAR INT, @MINDAY INT

SELECT @CURRENTYEAR = MIN([YEAR])
 , @STARTYEAR = MIN([YEAR])
 , @ENDYEAR = MAX([YEAR])
FROM #tmpHoliday

WHILE @CURRENTYEAR <= @ENDYEAR
 BEGIN
 SELECT @CNTR = COUNT([YEAR])
 FROM #tmpHoliday
 WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR

 SET @POS = 1

 WHILE @POS <= @CNTR
 BEGIN
 SELECT @MINDAY = MIN(DAY)
 FROM #tmpHoliday
 WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR
 AND [WEEK] IS NULL

 UPDATE #tmpHoliday
 SET [WEEK] = @POS
 WHERE [YEAR] = @CURRENTYEAR
 AND [DAY] = @MINDAY

 SELECT @POS = @POS + 1
 END

 SELECT @CURRENTYEAR = @CURRENTYEAR + 1
 END

UPDATE DT
SET HolidayText = 'Election Day'
FROM dbo.DimDate DT
JOIN #tmpHoliday HL
 ON (HL.DateID + 1) = DT.DateSK
WHERE [WEEK] = 1

DROP TABLE #tmpHoliday
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),113)--USED FOR CHECKING RUN TIME.

--DimDate indexes---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Date] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Day] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[Day] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DayOfWeek] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[DayOfWeek] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DOWInMonth] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[DOWInMonth] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_DayOfYear] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[DayOfYear] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_WeekOfYear] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[WeekOfYear] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_WeekOfMonth] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[WeekOfMonth] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Month] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[Month] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_MonthName] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[MonthName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Quarter] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[Quarter] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_QuarterName] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[QuarterName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DimDate_Year] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[Year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_dim_Time_HolidayText] ON [dbo].[DimDate] 
(
[HolidayText] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

PRINT convert(varchar,getdate(),113)--USED FOR CHECKING RUN TIME.
```

Comment: Why would you suggest creation of such a complex structure for such a simple problem?

Comment: @Declan_K why do you think a table of dates is so complex? What if the OP wants to include 0s for days or weeks where there is no data? How do you propose to fill the gaps? Please [read this post about calendar tables and how much utility they can provide](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3). Having a table on-hand can really simplify some of the outlandish workarounds people use to solve this type of problem.

Comment: @Declan_K Even though the script is somehow large, the structure can't be simpler. It's a dates table, with holidays included. What is the problem with giving a thorough answer?

Comment: It just feels really over-engineered to me, when all that is needed to solve the question at hand is some basic understand of DATE based calculations.

Comment: @Declan_K suggests to me that you haven't done a whole lot of complex date-driven queries. Could you expand on your answer and show how complex your query really gets then you need the query to cover eight weeks independently?

Comment: I'm not going to get into an arguement about how much code I've written, its counter-productive. I just feel that answers should be somewhat tailed to the precevied level of knowledge of the person asking it.

Comment: @Declan_K the idea is quite simple essentially this will eliminate the need for the op to do any sort of messing around for his dates. He will have a calendar table and if he ever needs any of the additional functionality that this table provides. Bam there it is! It solves his current problem with and takes care of any future complex date issues he can run into. Date tables are extremely useful.

Comment: @Declan_K it's a bit more work up front, but the downstream benefits are eminently useful and pay serious dividends.

Comment: Ive managed to get the data I needed using a MUCH easier way than this.

Comment: @user2371384 much easier than copy pasting this executing it and then joining to the table?

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to determine the Sunday of the current week. For that you need the following code

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

Now, in your query, make that a virtual table in the FROM Clause

```
FROM ...,(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS THIS_SUNDAY) SQ1
```

Then in your `WHERE` clause you can apply conditions like the followng which would give you orders for the previous week.

```
ORDER DATE >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,SQ1.THIS_SUNDAY) AND ORDER DATE < SQ1.THIS_SUNDAY
```

Comment: Please use code blocks and not backticks for highlighting code samples. Also, and definitely more importantly, [please don't suggest `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, edits apply.

Comment: Also you should note that `DATEPART` will rely on the local `DATEFIRST` setting.

Comment: Your last `<=` should be `<`. Otherwise it's just a bad `BETWEEN` clause in disguise.

Comment: Here is my code 'code'SELECT [OrderDate], COUNT(*) AS OrderTotal FROM [Orders] WHERE Order_Date between '2013/06/05' AND'2013/06/11' group by OrderComp'code'